# Fedora Virtualbox VM machine when clicked, details UI not visible

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, fedora

I am in Fedora and I have installed virtualbox latest, earlier it was showing the UI of a VM when I click on it but later on , I initiated File manager and now I can only see below components on the right side

1. Extensions
2. Media
3. Network
4. Cloud
5. Activities

When I click on any machine it is not showing any details, The UI shows me the active UI components from above. I checked everything in "User interface" inside settings but still no solution. I searched google but never found such issue by anyone. How do i bring the machine details back ?

[image]